# Switching a Linux server from one AD domain to Another

Tags: linux

I have a few Linux boxes that are part of an AD domain and they work just fine.

We recently switched to a new AD domain and I would like to "migrate" these Linux Machines over to the new domain.

I know how to add them to a domain, is changing them similar?

This is how I added them to AD:
http://anothersysadmin.wordpress.com/2007/08/03/active-directoy-authentication-with-ubuntu/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation for this is right in the `net` man page.

```
 $ net ads leave -U Adminstrator@domain

 ...re-work config files

 $ net ads join -U Administrator@domain
```